# How I can write a script that loops correctly, even if there is only one element in array?

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell

This topic is not related to AzurePowershell, but I was doing it and stuck in the problem, I will use as an example.

I have a code like this,

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName  "YouGo"  

$Sqldatabaseserver = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer
$ServerName = $Sqldatabaseserver | select -ExpandProperty ServerName

$ServerName

for($y = 0; $y -le $ServerName.Length -1; $y++){
  $YouGoServerNames = $ServerName[$y]
  $YouGoServerNames
  #Get-AzureSqlDatabase -ServerName $YouGoServerNames
}
```

when `$Servername` has more than one elements, and this script works like this

```
$ServerName
cat
fish
bird
horse
tiger
cat
fish
bird
horse
tiger
```

But When `$Servername` has only one element, it echoed out and  my script is not working.

```
dog
d
o
g
```

I would like to echo out like this, Like when `$ServerName` has multiple elements.

```
dog
dog
```

I would like to write a script that even `$Servename` has only one element or have multiple elements, the script works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$x = "abc" | select  -first 1
for($i = 0; $i -le $x.Length -1; $i++) { $x[$i] }

# a
# b
# c

$x.GetType().Name #String

$x = @("abc" | select  -first 1)
for($i = 0; $i -le $x.Length -1; $i++) { $x[$i] }

# abc

$x.GetType().Name #Array
```

So, your call:

```
$ServerName= $Sqldatabaseserver | select -ExpandProperty ServerName
```

should probably be rewritten:

```
$ServerName= @($Sqldatabaseserver | select -ExpandProperty ServerName)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can force it to be an array by wrapping it in the array operator `@()`:

```
$ServerName = @($Sqldatabaseserver | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerName)
```

This method used to be very common in early versions of PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to use use `Foreach` loop in spite of the `For` loop. `Foreach` will enter the loop even if it contains one element, even if it exits one elemnt it manage it as a collection :

```
$servername = "dog"
foreach ($srv in $servername) {Write-Host $srv}
```

gives :

```
"dog"
```